# Running 2 applications on port 80 with 2 different IP's

Tags: apache

I have 2 applications that I would like to run on my VPS listening on port 80. I have 2 IP's from the same machine. Would it be possible to do this? I heard people doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this using a reversed proxy. Each application runs on its own port. The reversed proxy will listen for a certain subdomain on port 80.

Answer (score -1):

It certainly is possible if each of the applications bind their respective server-socket to one of the IPs and not to `0.0.0.0`. What kind of applications are these?